# Getting more information about C5 model in tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels, c5.0

Here's a simple modelling workflow using the palmerpenguins dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
#> Warning: package 'parsnip' was built under R version 4.1.3
library(rules)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rules'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dials':
#> 
#>     max_rules
library(palmerpenguins)
#> Warning: package 'palmerpenguins' was built under R version 4.1.3


set.seed(2022)
penguins_split <- initial_split(penguins)
penguins_training <- training(penguins_split)
penguins_testing <- testing(penguins_split)

folds <- vfold_cv(penguins_training, v = 3)

simple_rec <- penguins_training %>% 
  recipe(species ~ .)

C5_model <- C5_rules() %>% 
  set_engine("C5.0")

penguins_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(simple_rec) %>% 
  add_model(C5_model)

penguins_no_tuning <- fit_resamples(
  object = penguins_wf,
  resamples = folds,
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
)
#> Warning: package 'C50' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1
#> v Fold1: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1
#> v Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1
#> v Fold2: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1
#> v Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1
#> v Fold3: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1
#> v Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions)

collect_metrics(penguins_no_tuning)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
#>   <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 accuracy multiclass 0.977     3 0.0134  Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 2 roc_auc  hand_till  0.985     3 0.00976 Preprocessor1_Model1

penguins_final_fit <- penguins_wf %>%
  last_fit(split = penguins_split)

collect_metrics(penguins_final_fit)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   .metric  .estimator .estimate .config             
#>   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 accuracy multiclass     0.942 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 2 roc_auc  hand_till      0.990 Preprocessor1_Model1

#Display rules
extract_fit_engine(penguins_final_fit) %>% 
  summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> C5.0.default(x = x, y = y, trials = trials, rules = TRUE, control
#>  = C50::C5.0Control(minCases = minCases, seed = sample.int(10^5,
#>  1), earlyStopping = FALSE))
#> 
#> 
#> C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]      Thu Mar 17 17:42:59 2022
#> -------------------------------
#> 
#> Class specified by attribute `outcome'
#> 
#> Read 258 cases (8 attributes) from undefined.data
#> 
#> Rules:
#> 
#> Rule 1: (73, lift 2.3)
#>  island in {Biscoe, Torgersen}
#>  flipper_length_mm <= 206
#>  ->  class Adelie  [0.987]
#> 
#> Rule 2: (98/18, lift 1.8)
#>  island in {Dream, Torgersen}
#>  bill_length_mm <= 46.5
#>  ->  class Adelie  [0.810]
#> 
#> Rule 3: (53, lift 4.7)
#>  island = Dream
#>  bill_length_mm > 42.2
#>  ->  class Chinstrap  [0.982]
#> 
#> Rule 4: (90, lift 2.8)
#>  island = Biscoe
#>  flipper_length_mm > 206
#>  ->  class Gentoo  [0.989]
#> 
#> Default class: Gentoo
#> 
#> 
#> Evaluation on training data (258 cases):
#> 
#>          Rules     
#>    ----------------
#>      No      Errors
#> 
#>       4    1( 0.4%)   <<
#> 
#> 
#>     (a)   (b)   (c)    <-classified as
#>    ----  ----  ----
#>     113                (a): class Adelie
#>       1    53          (b): class Chinstrap
#>                  91    (c): class Gentoo
#> 
#> 
#>  Attribute usage:
#> 
#>   99.61% island
#>   63.18% flipper_length_mm
#>   51.94% bill_length_mm
#> 
#> 
#> Time: 0.0 secs

#Model information?
extract_workflow(penguins_final_fit) 
#> == Workflow [trained] ==========================================================
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: C5_rules()
#> 
#> -- Preprocessor ----------------------------------------------------------------
#> 0 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> -- Model -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> C5.0 Model Specification ()

extract_workflow(penguins_final_fit) %>% 
  summary()
#>         Length Class      Mode   
#> pre     2      stage_pre  list   
#> fit     2      stage_fit  list   
#> post    1      stage_post list   
#> trained 1      -none-     logical
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I have three questions:

1. When displaying the rules, it says Evaluation on **training data** but `penguins_final_fit` was fitted on the test data using `last_fit()`. How do I get the model to output Evaluation on **test data** instead?
2. How do I get more information from the C5 model e.g. how deep did the tree go before pruning? `extract_fit_engine()` and `extract_workflow()` don't provide that information.
3. The auxiliary parameters for C5.0 [listed here](https://dials.tidymodels.org/reference/c5_parameters.html) - can these be tuned and, if so, where should these arguments be added? I took a look at `?C50::C5.0Control` and still didn't understand how to implement these in a tidymodels framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When [you use `last_fit()`](https://tune.tidymodels.org/reference/last_fit.html) you fit to the **training** data and evaluate on the **testing** data. If you look at the output of `last_fit()`, the metrics and predictions are from the testing data, while the fitted workflow was trained using the training data. You can [read more](https://www.tmwr.org/workflows.html#evaluating-the-test-set) about using the test set.
- You have [surfaced a bug in how we handle tuning engine-specific arguments in parsnip extension packages](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/691). I know this is inconvenient for you, but thank you for the report!

Comment: We also [have a feature request open](https://github.com/tidymodels/rules/issues/28) to make a `tidy()` method for the C5 model, so if you would use that, please add your thoughts there.